# php GD library sometimes generate blank image

Tags: php, gd

I trying to generate a signature from a name using the GD library, and return the png image in base64 format.

With the following code, the function correctly returns the base64 image with the signature:

```
<?php

function genSignature($name){
    // The text to draw
    $tamano = 15 * strlen($name);
    
    $fuentes = [
        '../fuentesFirma/HomemadeApple-Regular.ttf',
        '../fuentesFirma/Allura-Regular.ttf',
        '../fuentesFirma/DawningofaNewDay-Regular.ttf',
        '../fuentesFirma/HerrVonMuellerhoff-Regular.ttf',
        '../fuentesFirma/LaBelleAurore-Regular.ttf',
    ];
    
    $fuente = $fuentes[array_rand($fuentes, 1)];
    
    // Create the image
    $im = imagecreatetruecolor($tamano, 60);
    
    // Create some colors
    $white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
    $grey = imagecolorallocate($im, 128, 128, 128);
    $black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
    imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, $tamano, 60, $white);
    
    
    // Add the text
    imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 0, 30, $black, $fuente, $name);
    
    ob_start();
    imagepng($im);
    $buffer = ob_get_clean();
    ob_end_clean();
    return base64_encode($buffer);

}
echo genSignature('María'); //Commented line when calling from another script, for testing only.
```

But if I include the file with the function, and call it from another script, it always returns the same image, a white square (base64). I don't understant where is the problem..

Other script:

```
<?php
    include_once('generarFirma.php'); //in same folder
     //....
    //some operations...
    $signature = genSignature('María');
```

Comment: Could this be a simple caching problem? Windows: [ctrl] + [F5], Mac/Apple: [Apple] + [R] or [command] + [R], Linux: [F5].

Comment: I don't think so, GD is a php library, everything is executed on the server, I don't show anything on the screen.

Comment: This is not about beliefs. It's simple to test the given key strokes in your browser and then you know: If a signature shows it was a cache problem, if you still get the same it's not. Also, be precise in what you say: "don't show anything on the screen", is not the same as: "it always returns the same image, a white square (base64).".

Comment: I've tried clearing the cache, and it still doesn't work. If I directly execute the file "generarFirma.php" in the browser changing the name several times, it generates the base64 image correctly. But if I do it by including this file and calling the function from there, it always returns the same string (base64 image), which corresponds to a white square image.

Comment: OK. The paths to your font files are relative. Try to make them absolute and see if that helps?

Comment: OK, here was the problem! I guess the path to the fonts was failing, and with it the image creation processes. Thx!! :)

Comment: Nice. Yeah, relative paths are always a pain in PHP. Simply always use absolute paths to resource.

Comment: Use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` and then continue the file path `/some/location/file.php`.